# Why do they need to use the rings in the same order every time they need to call Captain Planet?

Tags: captain-planet

The order of the rings to be used when calling Captain Planet is Earth, Fire, Wind, Water, Heart.

Why does it have to be this order (other than the fact that it's the order shown in the opening)? Why is it always Kwami who initiated this? Can they call Captain Planet using some other order?

I vaguely remember in one of the episodes Wheleer (or someone) tells Kwami to "say it (let our powers combine)", that is, initiate the process to call Captain Planet, which indicates the order is important, but why is it? What happens if they use a different order?

In fact, when the villains call Captain Pollution, the order in which the counterpart evil rings is used is different (Super Radiation (Fire), Deforestation (Earth), Smog (Wind), Toxic Waste (Water), Hate (Heart))

What is the the significance of the order of the rings used to call Captain Planet?

Comment: Shot in the dark here: They drew the sequence once and edited it into every episode as is. In-universe I only found a possible reason why Kwame always initiates: he was the first planeteer summoned, but the rest of the order doesn't follow that pattern. Ma-Ti has most likely to be last, since he binds the four elemental powers of the others to create the Captain. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_element#Greece would suggest they use Aristotle in counter-clockwise order, with heart supplanting aether. Great question, +1.

Comment: @BMWurm - I remember the sequence being called on a number of occasions with different animation effects

Comment: @Richard Well, then my shot in the dark missed even more than I thought it would :P -- I thought about mentioning the Castle - 6x06 - Get a Clue, 30:39 min, where Castle talks about the order of importance of the classical Greek elements in medieval alchemy ... alas while it starts with Earth, it ends with Fire, and there is no confirmation it is actually true, and not just the Castle writers stating it is to fit there episode...

Comment: just for reference, here are three different animation sequences for summoning Captain Planet from different episodes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqJw01setW0,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxolK2EzDQY,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtUF1nEQ_2c

Comment: If I remember correctly the animation sequences in almost all episodes were different

Comment: @user13267 - Interesting, it appears that they're *compelled* to use them in that order.

Answer (score 2):

Happy to give you an official answer here from Captain Planet HQ and series Executive Producer and Co-Creator Barbara Pyle:

> Basically, the summoning is like a magic spell or ritual to summon Captain Planet - so Kwame saying "Let Our Powers Combine!" begins the process of bringing forth Captain Planet from the rings and the order is all part of this ritual. Without going through the process they would just use their powers normally.

Feel free to ask on [Captain Planet's Facebook Page](https://www.facebook.com/CaptainPlanet) in a message or post if you need confirmation. It is the Official Fan Page (as in it is run by the exec producers and creators of Captain Planet). It is a verified Facebook page with 500,000+ followers and very clearly the official page with license from Cartoon Network.

The Power Is Yours!

Comment: That link leads to "*The Official Facebook **fan page** of Captain Planet*" rather than something licensed by Turner or Hanna Barbera. Not that I doubt your sincerity, but can you offer any proof that this is more than just your opinion? For example, getting someone associated with the show to post this answer on their verified twitter feed, for example (e.g. https://twitter.com/captainplanetfd)

Comment: It is the Official Fan Page as in being a page for fans- it is run by the exec producers and creators of Captain Planet and it is a verified Facebook page with 500,000 + followers and very clearly the official page with license from Cartoon Network. I'm afraid that's all I can do for you.

Comment: I have incorporated the information from the comment above but I'm still looking for somewhere on that page where this answer is written out explicitly. Official site or not, it would be good to have a link to the exact post/quote from Barbara Pyle, would you know where that is?